# GraphView on Android draw string data

Tags: android, android-graphview

I have a temperature value from the Bluetooth device.

```
StringBuilder [] temp = new StringBuilder[1000];
```

it is not empty, it includes temperature value, for example, temp[1]=20, temp[2]=30 like this. But every one second this array change with news so my string is dynamic. I want to draw graph time-temp (x: time, y: temp) if I saw firstly temp[1] and draw ( a mean real-time graph). But the mean problem is, how can I draw the graph with the values (using Graphview library), I have StringBuilder and how to read them for the graph. ? Please help me I don't find any answer

Comment: Wht not add to `ArrayList` at 0 and reverse it. After some size remove last element before reverse.

Comment: What you mean i dont understand. I have temp[0] elements but i didnt write for example

Comment: And i have to use Stringbuilder

Comment: nobody help me ? what is your addvice ?

Comment: I provided my answear. i dont want to write whole code

Comment: i know but my Stringbuilder not convert double so i dont write in the datapoint function